How to implement dynamic RBAC in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I'm building an ASP.NET Core Web API, and my application will be used in a real-world environment. I need to implement dynamic Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) to manage user permissions, but I have no prior experience with RBAC or how to implement it.
What I need:

I want to create roles dynamically (i.e., add, update, delete roles from the system without hardcoding)
Assign specific permissions to each role (e.g., Create, Read, Update, Delete on resources like users, products, etc.)
Assign users to roles and manage their access based on permissions assigned to their role
Ensure the RBAC setup can scale and is secure.

My current setup:

ASP.NET Core Web API.
Using Entity Framework Core for database interactions.
SQL Server for the database.

My questions:

How should I structure my database tables to store roles, permissions,  and user-role mappings dynamically?
How do I handle authorization checks within my controllers (e.g., using [Authorize] attributes or middleware) based on the roles and permissions defined in the database?
Are there any best practices or libraries that would make implementing dynamic RBAC easier in ASP.NET Core?

Since the application is going to be used in a real-world scenario, I'm particularly concerned about security and scalability. Any guidance or examples on how to implement this?
Thanks in advance!

Hi @Nikusha Gabidzashvili,  suggest you can check the official document:Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core
